# Reduce gap between flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `<div>` container that is displayed as flex with the following CSS properties:

```
.icon-container {
    padding: 3px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: solid 2px white;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF44;
}
```

The html looks like:

```
<div class="icon-container">
    <img alt="icon 1" src="/images/icon1.png"><br>
    <img alt="icon 2" src="/images/icon2.png"><br>
    <img alt="icon 3" src="/images/icon3.png"><br>
    <img alt="icon 4" src="/images/icon4.png"><br>
    <img alt="icon 5" src="/images/icon5.png">
</div>
```

The resulting layout when I look at it under dev tools looks like:

[image]

I am trying to reduce the purple gaps by about half, but nothing seems to change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<br>` and use `row-gap`:

```css
.icon-container {
  padding: 3px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: solid 2px white;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF44;
  row-gap: 12px; /*  */
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
  <img alt="icon 1" src="/images/icon1.png">
  <img alt="icon 2" src="/images/icon2.png">
  <img alt="icon 3" src="/images/icon3.png">
  <img alt="icon 4" src="/images/icon4.png">
  <img alt="icon 5" src="/images/icon5.png">
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was trying row-gap, but evidently the `<br>`s created a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-grow: 0.8` and vary the value (0.8 in my example) up or down gradually until you find a solution that suits you.

Comment: This does not seem to change anything. My guess is something else is conflicting. The `<br>`s maybe?